# Browsing page siblings through next/previous links

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress as CMS for a site I'm developing. When I'm browsing posts, I can use Next/Previous links to walk between posts. I want to have the same thing on pages.

- Page A
- Page B
- Page C

Page A should link to next sibling Page B. Page B should link to previous sibling Page A and next sibling Page C. Page C should link to previous sibling Page B.

Is there any plugin you can recommend that generates these links? I know there are [some](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/next-page/) plugins that do this, but I specifically want one that hooks into my current theme automatically. I know how to edit the theme, but that would brick my site whenever a theme update is available.

I'm using the [LightWord](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/lightword) WordPress theme.

Comment: What would consist of a sibling page? Children of the same parent? Based upon date? Menu order?

Comment: Children of the same parent, order determined by menu order.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pop the following code into your functions.php file in your active theme directory:

```
function siblings($link) {
    global $post;
    $siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
    foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
        if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
            $ID = $key;
        }
    }
    $closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));

    if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') { echo $closest[$link]; } else { return $closest; }
}
```

To call the function:

```
<?php siblings('before'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php siblings('after'); ?>
```

and it will echo out the link to the previous or next page.

If you want both you can leave the function empty and it will return an array with both links.

Comment: The LightWord theme already has its own `functions.php`, so wouldn't a theme update brick this functionality?

Comment: Not a problem, just put it in as a child theme http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Steps include:
1) Make a second directory inside the themes directory with the name of the theme and '-child'
2) Create a file inside called style.css copy the header from the parent theme adding an additional line "template". Since this file will replace the style file of the parent make sure to import the content @import url("../LightWord/style.css");
3) functions.php does not replace the other functions file so you can add in the above code. 

There is a detailed explanation in the link posted in my comment above. But when you update the theme it will not affect this functionality.

Comment: I rewrote the function to fit my needs and it's working well. I had never heard of child themes before - great tip! Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is great jackreichert! How can I change it so that if their is not next or prev page nothing is returned? Thanks!

Comment: up vote 0 down vote
 

This is awesome!! I have been messing around with bad plugins to do this and I found this, so simple but so good. How could I use this and echoe the name of the previous or next page?

Comment: for those asking on how to echo, i use the quick and dirty way of the following codes http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/81237

Comment: this plugin has a few good functions to achieve the same - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/next-page/

Comment: How to modify this so it loops through the array ?

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to make it loop like onimojo asked for? I am also looking for this

Comment: On first glance this seems to work, but (at least on my site) it's not actually returning the correct links. It looks like this code is finding the siblings via page ID. That's OK if your page IDs are all the correct order, but I guess many people change the order of their pages manually using 'Order' in the admin backend. Maybe the answer could be edited to warn people it only returns the correct links if you haven't manually ordered the pages in the admin backend?

Comment: You might want to add out-of-bounds checking and handling for your array (in case there are no next/previous pages). Additionally, regarding the order: You can add the parameter `sort_column` with value `menu_order` to actually get the pages order as configured in WordPress and not ordered by name. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages. You can also specify other values.

Answer (score 9):

from the wordpress [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links#The_Next_and_Previous_Pages)

```
<?php
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
$pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>

<div class="navigation">
<?php if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
<div class="alignleft">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>"
title="<?php echo get_the_title($prevID); ?>">Previous</a>
</div>
<?php }
if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
<div class="alignright">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>" 
 title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">Next</a>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div><!-- .navigation -->
```

Comment: This works great! A bunch of other solutions are based on post ID, but this one using menu_order is just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A rough snippet of what I developed onwards from the answers here (to get a real link and the post title in action) - might prove helpful to someone!

```
$closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));
$name =  array('before'=>get_the_title($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_the_title($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));

if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') { 
echo '<a href="' . $closest[$link] . '">';
echo '<span>' . $name[$link] . '</span></a>';
}
else { return $closest; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here another function based on jackreichert's answer. With the added functionality that this wraps around to the last/first sibling when you are at the end of the list of siblings, so you can loop around endlessly. It also uses the menu order.

```
function get_sibling_link($link) {
    global $post;

    $siblings = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);

    foreach ($siblings as $key => $sibling){
        if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
            $current_id = $key;
        }
    }

    $closest = [ 
        'before' => get_permalink( $siblings[$current_id-1]->ID ),
        'after'  => get_permalink( $siblings[$current_id+1]->ID )
    ];

    if($siblings[$current_id-1]->ID == '' ){
        $closest['before'] = get_permalink( $siblings[count($siblings)-1]->ID );
    }

    if($siblings[$current_id+1]->ID == '' ){
        $closest['after'] = get_permalink( $siblings[0]->ID );
    }

    if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') { 
        echo $closest[$link]; 
    } else { 
        return $closest; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you- this helped develop my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

After trying several solutions, doing my best not to install another plugin, in the end the only thing that worked was a free plugin: [Next Page, Not Next Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/next-page-not-next-post/).

(I had issues with the solutions given here, I think perhaps because I *manually order* the pages in the Pages section of Wordpress Admin. You can select page order manually.  So my first page in the hierarchy might have an ID of 100, and the second page might have an ID of 10. The page ID is not how my pages get ordered.)

Answer (score -1):

```
 function siblings()
    {
        global $post;
        $args = array(
                        'sort_order'    => 'ASC',
                        'sort_column'   => 'menu_order',
                        'hierarchical'  => 1,
                        'child_of'      => $post->post_parent,
                        'parent'        => $post->post_parent,
                        'exclude_tree'  => '',
                        'offset'        => -1,
                        'post_type'     => 'page',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish'
            );
        $siblings = get_pages($args);

        foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling)
        {
            if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID)
            {
                $ID = $key;
            }
        }
        $closest = array(
                            'back'  => array('perm_link' => get_permalink(isset($siblings[$ID -1]->ID) ?  $siblings[$ID -1]->ID : $siblings[$ID]->ID), 'title' => get_the_title(isset($siblings[$ID -1]->ID) ?  $siblings[$ID -1]->ID : $siblings[$ID]->ID)),
                            'next'  => array('perm_link' => get_permalink(isset($siblings[$ID +1]->ID) ?  $siblings[$ID +1]->ID : $siblings[$ID]->ID) , 'title' => get_the_title(isset($siblings[$ID +1]->ID) ?  $siblings[$ID +1]->ID : $siblings[$ID]->ID))
                        );

        return $closest;

    }
```

and then use as this:

```
    <?php
$newrenderViews = new renderViews() ;
$back_next      = $newrenderViews->siblings();
$next           = $back_next['next'] ;
$next_title     = $next['title'] ;
$next_link      = $next['perm_link'] ;
$back           = $back_next['back'] ;
$back_title     = $back['title'] ;
$back_link      = $back['perm_link'] ;
?>

<div  class="section" >
    <div class="content_wrapper " style="background-color: #8A8C8F; width: 970px;">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
        <a href="<? echo $next_link; ?>" class="navbar-link" style="color: #ffffff;">Next - <?php echo $next_title ;  ?></a>
    </p>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
        <a href="<? echo $back_link; ?>" class="navbar-link" style="color: #ffffff;margin-left: 340px;">Go back - <?php  echo $back_title ;   ?></a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gives me an error: `Fatal error: Class 'renderViews' not found `

Comment: ouch my fault renderViews() should be a class having function siblings() ...