# wordpress how to navigate previous page and next page within the child pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am currently using the [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/next-page/) next page to add a previous page next page link to my wordpress site, however it is not working correctly as it sometimes messes up the order and it always jumps to the next parent page.

Is there a plugin or a way to get a link to the previous pages and next pages of child pages that runs in the sequence of the navigation and that doesn't jump to the next or previous parent page.

if you have a look at the bottom of the page on this [link](http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/rugs/animals/doves-and-stripes/) you will see that its saying the next page is fish white, when in fact it is fish blue.

How can I fix this issue, I am happy to use a jquery fix too?

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browsing page siblings through next/previous links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533407/browsing-page-siblings-through-next-previous-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works well

[Browsing page siblings through next/previous links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533407/browsing-page-siblings-through-next-previous-links)