# Navigating through Wordpress sibling pages using functions.php

Tags: wordpress, navigation, siblings

I'm trying to find a way to get through sibling pages on my wordpress hosted site. After a bit of searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533407/browsing-page-siblings-through-next-previous-links) to put into my functions.php:

```
function siblings($link) {
global $post;
$siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
    if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
        $ID = $key;
    }
}
$closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));

if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') { echo $closest[$link]; } else { return $closest; } }
```

It's almost perfect for what I need. The only problems are:

1. It sorts them alphabetically and I need them sorted by the Order Number
2. I need it to loop (so the last pages links to the first) and not just end
3. It automatically says "Previous of Next" and I would like to get rid of that "of"

If anyone has input on any of the three issues, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm doing some tinkering myself but I figured that most of you are probably a lot better at this than I am. That, and I've gotten "500 Server Errors" one too many times.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is your modified piece of code. It solves your first two requests. The last one is not part of provided code. This code does not generate either of mentined words. It only echoes or returns permalinks.

```
function siblings($link) {
global $post;
$siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent.'&sort_column=menu_order');
foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
    if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
        $ID = $key;
    }    
}

if( $ID == 0 ){
    $closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[count($siblings)-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));  
}elseif( $ID == count($siblings)-1 ){
    $closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[0]->ID));
}else{
    $closest = array('before'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID-1]->ID),'after'=>get_permalink($siblings[$ID+1]->ID));   
}

if ($link == 'before' || $link == 'after') { echo $closest[$link]; } else { return $closest; } }
```

**EDIT:** Added **&sort_column=menu_order** to get_pages arguments to solve first request

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That only solved the second one, though, and not the first one. It's still ordering them alphabetically.

Either way, thank you.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. Any idea where I might have to look to change the "of" bit I was talking about? If not, that's fine, you've been a wonderful help already.

Comment: Should be in a part of your template file where you do call siblings() function...

Comment: Mark my answer as right answer would be nice, thanks in advanced.