# Cycle Through Wordpress Child Pages Sorting by Order Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone know anything about controlling the ordering of Wordpress child pages? The "order" attribute seems to be being ignored in favor of alphabetical order.

```
<a href="<?php siblings('before'); ?>">Prev</a>
<a href="<?php siblings('after'); ?>">Next</a>
```

This code was extracted from another answer here, and works as expected except Order Attribute is ignored in favor of Alphabetical order. ([Browsing page siblings through next/previous links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533407/browsing-page-siblings-through-next-previous-links))

I feel like what I need will look something like **ORDER BY 'menu_order'** but I don't fully understand the syntax or where to place this within:

```
function siblings($link) {
    global $post;
    $siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
    foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
        if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
            $ID = $key;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   $siblings = get_pages(array(
       'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
       'parent' => $post->post_parent,
       'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
));
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, the pages don't change at all. I tried  **$siblings = get_pages('child_of=&sort_column=menu_order'.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent );** with the original bit of code but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
function siblings($link) {
    global $post;
    $siblings = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&sort_column=menu_order&parent='.$post->post_parent);
    foreach ($siblings as $key=>$sibling){
        if ($post->ID == $sibling->ID){
            $ID = $key;
        }
    }
```

Ended up working.