# Wordpress - Next and previous page (not post) cycling links

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a very simple website where the navigation is only by 'next' and 'previous' buttons which load the respective pages.

I have implemented this solution which works great:
[Browsing page siblings through next/previous links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533407/browsing-page-siblings-through-next-previous-links/30442727#30442727)

However, when I navigate to the last page, I want the 'next' link to cycle back to the beginning, so you could carry on clicking and cycling through the pages.

Appreciate any help on this, I'm stumped!